# Aparece error Quota Exceeded en los tableros de PowerBI al leer datos de BigQuery

Tags: powerbi, google-bigquery

Diariamente subo una base de datos local con un proceso de python a BigQuery, guardo las tablas en un dataset (50 tablas) Hasta ahí todo bien, están actualizadas en la nube.

Luego desde mis 10 tableros de PowerBI consumo esos datos con una cuenta de servicio, para mostrar los gráficos. De un momento a otro empezaron a aparecer errores de sincronización con BigQuery.

El error completo es este:
Error del origen de datos: [ValidateMarkupTags][ccon]DataSource.Error: ODBC: [ccon]ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][BigQuery] (115) Operation timeout. Error happened in ExecuteRetriable. Error Code:403. Error Message:Quota exceeded: Your project exceeded quota for free query bytes scanned.

For more information, see [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas[/ccon]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas%5B/ccon%5D). DataSourceKind = [ccon]GoogleBigQuery[/ccon]. DataSourcePath = [ccon]GoogleBigQuery[/ccon]. OdbcErrors = [ccon]#table({"SQLState", "NativeError", "Message"}, {})[/ccon]. [/ccon]. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface. Table: RESERVA.

En el log de cuotas de bigquery esta todo disponible, el que mas consumo tiene dice 0.5% en uso. Tengo asociado el proyecto a una cuenta de facturación y al día. Con la carga de datos a la nube y consumo desde PBI no hay 1.500 trabajos de carga ni de casualidad (leí que es el tope de ejecuciones diarias por proyecto)

Entonces no comprendo porque de un día a otro empezaron a fallar. Incluso a veces se actualizan, pero la mayoría de los intentos fallan.

Gracias por ayudarme!!

Comment: Tienes agregado el Billing en source? 
Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject="projectname", UseStorageApi=false])

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

El error "**Quota Exceeded**" en Power BI al leer datos de BigQuery puede deberse a que se hayan superado los límites de cuota de BigQuery. Aunque menciona que tiene un abono sin límite de cuota en BigQuery, es posible que algunos de los límites predeterminados estén causando el problema. Para resolver este error, es recomendable analizar la carga de trabajo para mitigar el problema, optimizar la carga de trabajo o solicitar un aumento de cuota. También se sugiere habilitar la facturación en su cuenta para acceder a más almacenamiento, como lo dice la [documentación](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/troubleshoot-quotas?hl=es)

Si el límite de cuota se excede ocasionalmente, se puede implementar reintentos en este error específico con un retraso exponencial. Además, considerar el uso de inserciones de transmisión, ya que las inserciones de transmisión no se ven afectadas por la API de BigQuery.

También se menciona en este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430496/how-to-deal-with-big-query-error-403-quota-exceeded) que el límite de operaciones de tabla por día es de 1,500 en tablas estándar, por lo que si se alcanza este límite, los trabajos de BigQuery fallarán con el error "**Quota Exceeded**".

En resumen, para abordar el error "Quota Exceeded" al leer datos de BigQuery en Power BI, es recomendable analizar y, si es necesario, ajustar los límites de cuota de BigQuery, así como optimizar la carga de trabajo y considerar el uso de inserciones de transmisión en lugar de operaciones de tabla estándar.

Comment: Entiendo su preocupación, pero Chat GPT no se ha utilizado para brindar una posible solución al problema actual. Así mismo te invito a leer las fuentes que dejé, donde podrás encontrar la información dada en la respuesta.